# get encoder file name in postman

Tags: java, postman, encoder

My API have file download controller, file name on cyrillic. In Postman Send and Download give me file name like:

%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9.docx

When i send request in chrome i get right file name on cyrillic like:

русский.docx

Corresponding line of my api java code:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + URLEncoder.encode(fileName, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

How get right file name on cyrillic in Postman?

In Crome i have

[image]

after request file automatically downloaded

[image]

In Postman
[image]

Comment: the code is from postman or your api?

Comment: Code - my api on java

Comment: could you add relevant postman and chrome screen shot to show the different the file name shown is actual url encoded value of русский.docx ,

Comment: hello, do you solve this problem,i occur this too.